# How to group by non consecutive Vec elements in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec<(A, B)>` and I want to group by `A` but not just consecutive but all elements in the `Vec`. The closest thing I found is [`Itertools::group_by`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.6.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by) which only works on consecutive values. I understand that the consecutiveness is related to optimizing allocation but I just want a regular C# group by. Priority is to not have to use a new library just for this.

`A` is not hashable, only `Ord`. I want a resulting `Vec<(A, Vec<(A, B))>` or equivalent

Comment: As in you have a `Vec<(A, b)>` and you want groups of `B` based on `A`?

Comment: Also, what trait implementations are `A` guaranteed to have? If it has `Hash`, then this can be easily done by folding onto a `HashMap<A, Vec<B>>`.

Comment: Related: [How to fold using a HashMap as an accumulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884309/how-to-fold-using-a-hashmap-as-an-accumulator) Instead of counting, just append to the vector.

Comment: If `A: Ord`, you can also use a `BTreeMap` instead of a `HashMap`.

Comment: Does "comparable" mean `A: Eq`, `A: Ord`, `A: PartialEq` or `A: PartialOrd`?

Comment: it is partial ord

Comment: @ditoslav With just `PartialOrd`, you don't even have the guarantee that `a == a` for all elements of `A`. It's completely unclear what grouping even means in that context.

Comment: guys, I'm new to rust, help me out. As I said, I want something similar to C# group_by. If I need the Eq and I forgot PartialOrd doesn't have it then can't you assume I wanted Org which has it. You don't have to be so hostile

Comment: @ditoslav Hey, slowly! I really didn't mean to be hostile – it's just that these differences _matter_ for the solution. I already provided an answer for the case that `A: Ord`, but if you only have `A: PartialOrd` this will be useless for you. And regarding "can't you assume I wanted Or[d]", well, that's exactly what I did in the first sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming that "comparable" means `A: Ord`, i.e. that there is a total ordering on `A`, you can fold an iterator over items of type `(A, B)` into a `BTreeMap` from `A` to `Vec<B>`:

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn group_pairs<A, B, I>(v: I) -> BTreeMap<A, Vec<B>>
where
    A: Ord,
    I: IntoIterator<Item = (A, B)>,
{
    v.into_iter().fold(BTreeMap::new(), |mut acc, (a, b)| {
        acc.entry(a).or_default().push(b);
        acc
    })
}
```

Some people prefer a for loop over a fold:

```
fn group_pairs<A, B, I>(v: I) -> BTreeMap<A, Vec<B>>
where
    A: Ord,
    I: IntoIterator<Item = (A, B)>,
{
    let mut result = BTreeMap::<A, Vec<B>>::new();
    for (a, b) in v {
        result.entry(a).or_default().push(b);
    }
    result
}
```

Example:

```
let data = vec![(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 5)];
let grouped = vec![(1, vec![2, 1]), (2, vec![3, 4]), (3, vec![5])];
assert_eq!(group_pairs(data).into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>(), grouped);
```

Comment: *I want a resulting `Vec<(A, Vec<(A, B))>`* — you may want to touch on why they cannot have that exact type with the requirements they've provided.

Comment: See also [How to use a struct's member as its own key when inserting the struct into a map without duplicating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41035869/155423)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the fold is extremely succinct while doing exactly what was required